# Accessing Redux from normal JS file which is not component

Tags: reactjs

In our react.js website we made a javascript file that contains the base url to create axios and write the code only once and use it whenever we went to send request to the database , the problem is we need to access Redux from this normal javascript file which is not a component . is there a way to access redux from it?

Comment: Is this file a non-react component? If it only does requests and so, you probably would like to create a saga  with this code and apply the redux-saga as middleware of your app.

Comment: export store from app.js and import that within your js file

Comment: the store is not in app.js it is a file inside the containers @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Comment: thank you i will try it after finishing the current approach @RenanBandeira

Comment: what kind of containers?

Comment: sorry it is my fault the store just is in separate folder @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Answer (score 4):

Need to call `getState` from store. Here is an example:

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT':
    return state + 1
  case 'DECREMENT':
    return state - 1
  default:
    return state
  }
}
​
let store = createStore(counter)
export { store }
```

​
**normal-javascript-file.js**

```
import { store } from './store.js'

// you can call getState() to get current store state.
console.log(store.getState())
```

If your normal javascript file is not bundled with react-app, you need to assign store instance to window object to make it globally available everywhere:

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT':
    return state + 1
  case 'DECREMENT':
    return state - 1
  default:
    return state
  }
}
​
let store = createStore(counter)
window.appStore = store

export default store
```

**normal-javascript-file.js**

```
var store = window.appStore

console.log(store.getState())
```

Comment: the problem is i have a default export  in store.js and i am not allowed to have more than one default export

Comment: @omarelgaml in fact you are not limited to default exports. You can use named exports: `export { store }` and import it as `import { store } from './store.js'

Comment: I did not mean that. Read my commend carefully again. I've also updated my answer.

Comment: Not you brother. I know we have named export and default export

Comment: @OlimSaidov it gives me a zero in the console when I cosole.log(store.getState())

Comment: @omar elgam Try to dispatch some actions and call getState again

Comment: @OlimSaidov it gives now an error cannot read property 'getState' of undefined